How to use Parallel.ForEachAsync to call http request to process multi eventstream responses?
OS Name:     Mac OS X
OS Version:  13.4
OS Platform: Darwin
RID:         osx-arm64
.net core:Version:      8.0.1
I want to request an event stream url using the following code, which runs normally.

 private async Task<IList<RepoInfo>> GetSearchResult(string url)
        {
            var repoList = new List<RepoInfo>();
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {

                try
                {

                    var stream = await client.GetStreamAsync(url);
                    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
                    {
                        while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
                        {
                            var m =  streamReader.ReadLine();
                            if (m != null && m.StartsWith("data: {\"filename\":\"package.json\""))
                            {

                                var contentInfo = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ContentInfo>(repoString);
  repoList.Add(contentInfo.repo);
                                
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message, "ddddd");
                }


            }
            return repoList;
        }

   public async Task<IList<RepoInfo>> SearchDependencies(string searchName)
        {

            var url = this.BuildSearchUrl(searcheLib);
            return await this.GetSearchResult(url);
        }


private async Task ExcuteSearchGitLabSubAll(CommandOPtions commandOPtions)
    {
        List<RepoInfo> repoInfos = new List<RepoInfo>();

   
        var packages = [];


        foreach (var packageName in packages)
        {

                var result = await SearchDependencies(packageName);
                if (result != null)
                {
                    repoInfos.AddRange(result);
                       Console.WriteLine("------------{0},{1}", "completed!!", packageName);
                }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("------------{0},{1}", "completed All!!", path);
    }

However, if I want to execute it in parallel, the program will terminate without waiting for all tasks to finish.
private async Task ExcuteSearchGitLabAll(CommandOPtions commandOPtions)
    {

        var allLibs = Const.fileList;
        List<RepoInfo> repos = new List<RepoInfo>();

   
          await  Parallel.ForEachAsync(allLibs, async (lib,token) =>
            {

                var result = await codeBaseService.SearchDependencies(lib);
                repos.AddRange(result);
            });

        });
        Console.WriteLine("------------{0}", "completed All!!");


    }

